# Find the volume common to the surfaces $y^2+z^2=4ax$ and $x^2+y^2=2ax$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Find the volume common to the surfaces $y^2+z^2=4ax$ and $x^2+y^2=2ax$

I set up the following integral :

$$\iiint_{z=-\sqrt{4ax-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax-y^2}}\,dz\,dy\,dx = 2\cdot \int_{x=0}^{2a} \int_{y=-\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}} \sqrt{4ax-y^2}\,dy\,dx$$

Which is not easy to integrate.

If I use polar coordinates the integration becomes

$$2\cdot \int_{\theta=-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{r=0}^{2a\cos(\theta)} \sqrt{4ar\cos(\theta)-r^2\sin^2(\theta)} \cdot r\,dr\,d\theta$$

Which is again difficult

Comment: When you see $x^2+y^2=4ax,$ you should think of completing the square:
$$
(x^2-4ax+4a^2) + y^2 = 4a^2
$$
$$
(x-2a)^2+y^2 = (2a)^2
$$
This is a cylinder of radius $2a$ whose center line is at $x=2a,\,y=0,$ parallel to the $z$-axis. $\qquad$

Comment: This is an extremely awkward problem. Are you sure there's no mistake? @MichaelHardy: It's actually an offset cylinder of radius $a$, but does that observation actually help? I don't see how.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Why would you say radius $a$ rather than radius $2a. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: The $4$ appears in the equation of the paraboloid, and a $2$ appears in the equation of the cylinder.

Comment: I agree it is awkward. But I've rechecked and see that it's written correctly.

Comment: oh. Alright: $$ x^2+y^2 = 2ax $$ $$ (x^2 - 2ax +a^2) + y^2 = a^2 $$ $$ (x-a)^2 + y^2 = a^2 $$ So the center line is $x=a,\, y=0$ and the radius is $a. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I did that. That's how I got the both integrals

Comment: Well, no, you ended up with a polar coordinate integral based on the origin. With Michael's observation, you can do polar coordinates centered at $(a,0)$ instead, but you get an equally appalling integral.